# CSS not working after upgrade to Jakarta EE 9/Primefaces 10

Tags: css, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

On a JSF page, an external CSS file is included as follows:

```
<f:facet name="last">    
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="custom.css" />
</f:facet>
```

In this file a class is defined:

```
.myCustomClass{ 
    background:#D94040;
}
```

And last, this `.class` is assigned to an p element:

```
<p:column class="myCustomClass">
```

This works fine with Java EE 8/Primefaces 8. But after upgrading to Jakarta EE 9/Primefaces 10, the CSS are no longer applied.

Does anyone have an idea why the background color is no longer displayed in the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: Can be anything at this point. Is you CSS file loaded? Is the style overridden by a more specific style in PF component or theme style sheet? You need to debug this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles

Comment: Yes the base styles in PF10 have changed if you are using a theme like Nova-Light.  Its possible your CSS is being overridden by a PF theme style?  Debug in the Chrome CSS Inspector.